# Visual studio cordova sql server tutorial

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am newbie to mobile development. For this i started working on `cordova` in visual studio. There is a [weather](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/) app tutorial in visual studio, but i can't find any tutorial which links `sql server` with cordova app, all i can find is with `SQLite` or `MySQL`. I want to connect my `local DB` with the app directly.

Kindly help me out on this, as i am stuck to it almost 3 weeks.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i can't find any tutorial which links sql server with cordova app, all i can find is with SQLite or MySQL. I want to connect my local DB with the app directly.

Currently there is no way to connect to `sql server` directly in Cordova.

You need to implement a service layer for data exposion of your database. You can leverage [mssql for node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) if you are familar with javascript. Alternatively, [ASP.Net Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api) is a good choice, if you are more familar with `.Net`.

Whatever the technology you use to build the service layer. It will eventually be consumed by your cordova app through [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).